# Invalid CSS errors in Ruby

Tags: css, ruby

I keep getting "Invalid CSS" errors from the Action Controller, such as the following:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Todos#index
Invalid CSS after "  text-align": expected ";", was ": right"
```

My CSS is valid, as far as I can tell:

```
table {
  width: 80%;
}

th {
  height: 20px;
}

.description {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.days_old {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.completed {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The errors that keep popping up are all pointing out correct css as "invalid." If I delete or comment out one line, the next comes up as an error.

I called my TodoIndex.css.scss file this way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "TodoIndex", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Can someone help me find what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your whole `.scss` file? Are there maybe any fancy characters beside whitespaces? Like tabs or your `-` in text-align?

Comment: Sounds like a missing semicolon or brace somewhere.